# Check if Cacti Boost is currently running

Tags: linux, shell, cacti

How can I find out whether the boost update process is running presently on Cacti? I want to check in a script before I start the regular system backup, delay my backup if it's boost is still running so that I don't overload the system and avoid the gaps I have around the time of my backup..

Answer (score 0):

You can check by running `ps -ef` amd seeing if  `/var/www/html/cacti/plugins/boost/poller_boost.php` is running.

That said, the path may be different for you, but there should still be a process with `cacti/plugins/boost/poller_boost.php` in it.

Comment: No because boost_server.php is ..the boost server it stays on like a daemon ready to write any graph data from the db to the rrds in case someone opens a cacti page and the graphs haven't been updated yet.